# what's the meaning of "naturally replenished"?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "naturally replenished"?

e.g.

El Paso receives its water supply from a set of aquifers as well as from the Rio Grande, but the supply, upon which soils used for agriculture are also dependent, **is not being naturally replenished**

Comment: It means that rainfall isn't filling the aquifers as fast as El Paso is draining them.

Answer (score 2):

Just take each word separately: Naturally in this case means "by nature". Replenished means refilled or restored.

Your sentence is pointing out the fact that the water supply is not refilled by nature such as by rain or other water supplies.